# Authentication framework for VSTO MS-word addin

Tags: ms-word, vsto, office-addins, office-automation

We are developing an MS word VSTO add-in. The application is very simple, it has task pane which has a search functionality. Once users get the results and clicks on the search results, we load the results into the word document.

All this is done through RestAPI's. Now is the time for us to include authentication in the task pane. Our use case is that if the user has never logged in we would prompt the user to provide username and password, which will be posted to the "Authentication Service" that we have already developed and are using from other projects too. Once the user is authenticated, authentication service will provide an access token to the client. My Question is as follows

1) What are the best practices for achieving authentication in VSTO MS word?

2) My understanding is that VSTO doesn't have session objects as it is not a traditional web application. How do we make connections to authentication service?

3)  Once the connection is made, where do we store the access token?

Any help on this is hugely appreciated. I am no expert in VSTO technology so some of the things that I may have asked here might seem childish :)

Thanks

Comment: VSTO doesn't have any such mechanism built-in, whatever you do will have to come from somewhere else. A VSTO project is still a C#/VBA project so whatever you would otherwise do to accomplish this normally can still be done in a VSTO add-in.

Comment: Thanks Chris, do you have any suggestions for storing the access token?

Comment: Nope, sorry. It's not something I've ever done.